# 502 Bad Gateway Docker proxy reverse con SSL para varios dominios

Tags: docker, nginx

estoy trabajando con Docker usando `nginx proxy reverse`, me encontré con un error que probablemente sea de mi configuración que tengo al levantar contenedores.

Al crear contenedores con subdominios por ejemplo: example.midominio.com, sin certificado ejecuta bien y levanta el contenedor al igual que puedo visualizar el html en el navegador, pero al levantar un contenedor con un dominio: midominio.com me marca un error en el navegador de 502.

Esto es lo que ejecutó para levantar un subdominio:

```
docker run -d --name example.midominio.com --expose 80  --net nginx-proxy --link mariadb:mariadb -v /home/ec2-user/userecommerce/$1/html:/var/www/html -e VIRTUAL_HOST=example.midominio.com -e VIRTUAL_PROTO=http -e VIRTUAL_PORT=80  -e HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect ecommercefya:v3
```

Esto es lo que ejecutó para levantar un dominio:

```
docker run -d --name midominio.com --expose 80 --expose 443 --net nginx-proxy --link mariadb:mariadb -v /home/ec2-user/userecommerce/midominio.com/html:/var/www/html -e VIRTUAL_HOST=midominio.com -e VIRTUAL_PROTO=http -e VIRTUAL_PORT=80 -e VIRTUAL_PROTO=https -e VIRTUAL_PORT=443 -e HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect ecommercefya:v3
```

Este es el comando para levantar el nginx-proxy:

```
docker run -d --name nginx-proxy --net nginx-proxy -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -e HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect -e HSTS=off -v /home/ec2-user/ssl:/etc/nginx/certs -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Al ejecutar docker logs en el nginx-proxy:

> 2019/12/16 18:55:15 [error] 545#545: *1837 connect() failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   200.14.138.67, server: minubeya.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.24.0.4:443/favicon.ico", host:
>   "minubeya.com", referrer: "http://example.midominio.com"

Y en mi contenedor con certificado ssl y dominio:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.24.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.24.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Dec 16 16:42:37.897214 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.2.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 16 16:42:37.897270 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Este es el contenido de mi default.conf:

```
# minubeya.com
upstream example.midominio.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "nginx-proxy" network
                        # minubeya.com
                        server 172.24.0.4:443;
}
server {
        server_name example.midominio.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/minubeya.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/minubeya.com.key;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/minubeya.com.chain.pem;
        location / {
                proxy_pass example.midominio.com;
        }
}
server {
        server_name example.midominio.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass example.midominio.com;
        }
}
```

Este es el contenido de mi nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
daemon off;
```

Comment: Listo amigo los acabo de agregar

Comment: Agrege el contenido de mi default.conf y nginx.conf la verdad es tu tema nuevo para mi el agregar SSL a varios dominios con docker y nginx reverse normalmente trabajo con subdominios

Comment: Como comento soy un poco nuevo en esto disculpa por los errores.
Pero si lo cambio a http que no afectaría si quiero entrar por medio de https ya que le estoy agregando su certificado al dominio minubeya? Cómo definiría el https en mi nginx.conf?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102261/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-abraham-najera).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es simple, al trabajar con docker no debes usar ip para el/los servicios, debes usar el nombre asignado al contenedor; cambia las siguiente lineas:

```
upstream server_example.midominio.com { #cambio el nombre para que sea mas facil identificar
                                ## Can be connected with "nginx-proxy" network
                        # minubeya.com
                        server example.midominio.com #NOMBRE DEL CONTENEDOR
}
```

Una vez realizado el cambio , todos los proxy_pass relacionados al server  debes colocar el del `upstream`; tu virtualhost quedara de la siguiente forma:

```
upstream server_example.midominio.com { #cambio el nombre para que sea mas facil identificar
                                ## Can be connected with "nginx-proxy" network
                        # minubeya.com
                        server example.midominio.com #NOMBRE DEL CONTENEDOR
}
server {
        server_name example.midominio.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/minubeya.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/minubeya.com.key;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/minubeya.com.chain.pem;
        location / {
                proxy_pass server_example.midominio.com;
        }
}
server {
        server_name example.midominio.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass server_example.midominio.com;
        }
}
```

> ADICIONAL:

puedes verificar los logs de los contenedores usando el comando

```
docker logs <id_contenedor>
```

Si quieres garantizar que tus cambios se encuentran dentro del contenedor puedes acceder usando el comando:

```
docker exec -it <id_o_nombre_conteneedor> bash
```

Donde `i= interactive` y `t = TTY`